# How can one start a process and monitor its syslog messages?

Tags: logs

I would like to start a process and monitor its LOG_DEBUG syslog messages.

I know that I can change the filter of an *already running* process with `syslog -c process` (and then monitor its messages with `syslog -w -k Sender process`), but that requires the process already to be running and furthermore fills up logfiles with messages that I only need temporarily.

Is my only option to change the running configuration with `syslog -config`, then later restore the configuration once I have read the messages I want?  Surely there is a "better" way.

Comment: Not completely sure what you're asking for; if it's a temporary solution, you already included it in your question (wouldn't be to complicated to put in a .sh script) if it's a more long-term thing you should configure `/etc/asl.conf` with something like `[= Sender exampleApp] [< Level Error] file exampleApp.log`. In any case if you want to log something, you need to store it somewhere; whether it's a file or "only" printed on your screen, it's using more or less the same resources.

Answer (score -1):

Using the tail command in Terminal.app will follow a log file and print out in real time whats being written to just that log file.

```
tail -f /path/to/your/log/file.log
```

If your process has a common name that shows in every log file, like *com.my.process* you can tail the file and grep out for that keyword/process.

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log | grep "com.my.process"
```

[tail command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tail.1.html)

Comment: I think this rather misses the point of my question.  I'm trying to avoid (a) writing these messages to the filesystem; and (b) making anything more than an ephemeral change to syslog's configuration.  Use of `tail` in this fashion necessitates both.